# C# - Load dictionary of Hashsets from an XML file using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file containing identifiers that I would like to add to a dictionary of hashsets to later parse.

I am confused on how to fill this Dictionary of Hashsets from the XML file using linq. I have tried to use other posts on stackoverflow but my XML file is filled up differently than others I have seen.

Currently my XML file looks like this:

```
    <Release_Note_Identifiers>
      <Identifier container ="Category1">
        <Container_Value>Old</Container_Value>
        <Container_Value>New</Container_Value>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier container ="Category2">
        <Container_Value>General</Container_Value>
        <Container_Value>Liquid</Container_Value>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier container ="Category3">
        <Container_Value>Flow Data</Container_Value>
        <Container_Value>Batch Data</Container_Value>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier container ="Category4">
        <Container_Value>New Feature</Container_Value>
        <Container_Value>Enhancement</Container_Value>
      </Identifier>
    </Release_Note_Identifiers>
```

I would like to add all of this to a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>()`where the key is each category and the hashset contains each container value.

I want to make this as abstract as possible because I want to eventually add more categories and add more container values for each category.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this setup code:

```
var contents = @"    <Release_Note_Identifiers>
    <Identifier container =""Category1"">
        <Container_Value>Old</Container_Value>
        <Container_Value>New</Container_Value>
    </Identifier>
    <Identifier container =""Category2"">
        <Container_Value>General</Container_Value>
        <Container_Value>Liquid</Container_Value>
    </Identifier>
    <Identifier container =""Category3"">
        <Container_Value>Flow Data</Container_Value>
        <Container_Value>Batch Data</Container_Value>
    </Identifier>
    <Identifier container =""Category4"">
        <Container_Value>New Feature</Container_Value>
        <Container_Value>Enhancement</Container_Value>
    </Identifier>
    </Release_Note_Identifiers>";
var xml = XElement.Parse(contents);
```

... the following will give you what you want.

```
var dict = xml.Elements("Identifier")
    .ToDictionary(
        e => e.Attribute("container").Value,
        e => new HashSet<string>(
            e.Elements("Container_Value").Select(v=> v.Value)));
```

Comment: This worked well! Thank you so much. Is the way I created the XML document good? I've noticed it is different from others I have seen on stackoverflow

Comment: @user3369494: It's hard to say what's "good" without knowing more about the type of data you're dealing with. It looks valid enough.